# ArcMap MXD that was opened from ArcGIS Online keeps crashing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online

I opened up a webmap from ArcGIS Online in ArcMap as an MXD. The map has several hosted feature layers. I have been working on it for hours and all of a sudden the map crashed on me and I cannot open it. This is the second time it’s happened with a different MXD. Has anyone else ever come across this?